# Place text on same height as image

Tags: css, html

I have a image, to the right of which is some text. The problem is that to image is taller than the text, this looks weird. How can I have the same amount of image above and below the text.

**Image needs to move up a bit, or text needs to move down a bit.**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logoandtext">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fb7Zfbc.png" tite="Red Logo" alt="<Logo>">
         <h1 class="title">Red is a color.</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333333;
    width: 600px;
}
h1 {
    text-shadow: #6A6A6A 1px -2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px
}
.logoandtext img {
    float: left;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvf4gqfp/3/)**

Comment: add padding-top: 18px; to h1

Comment: @nk-47 adding padding would improve the appearance, but it's abit messy, especially if you have lots of images of different heights then you'll end up with lots of different rules applying different paddings. The easiest to maintain solution (and most reliable) would probably be a `vertical-align` rule

Comment: @MLeFevre I know, the question was for a specific 100px image that's why I gave a quick (not so general) solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to make the text's container have a line-height the same as the height of the image, so for example:

```
h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvf4gqfp/4/

Or remove your float and vertically align your elements to the middle

```
h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvf4gqfp/20/

Comment: Which of these two methods is better?

Comment: @Vader Personally i'd say the `vertical-align` method is better. For example: if you were to change the size of your image, it would automatically deal with it and keep the alignment correct, whereas if you used `line-height` you'd have to remember to change that as well. There are some cases where i could imagine `line-height` working better (long sentences with a lot of text and different images spanning multiple lines), but for the example in your question, `vertical-align` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

add this code it will work:

```
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 49px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvf4gqfp/22/

Comment: I want to avoid giving specifics like `49px` because that is only guaranteed to work in this setup.

Comment: @Vader then give it in %.

Answer (score 3):

Use the follwing CSS which vertically aligns the h1 with the img. The img display is set to inline (instead of floating it). Both the img and h1 were vertically aligned. Also the extra margins of h1 were removed.

```
h1 {
    text-shadow: #6A6A6A 1px -2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.logoandtext img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvf4gqfp/16/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the image (because you're floating it).

The text is technically in the middle of the `div`.

You could make both `inline-block;` instead of just the image as `float:left;`.

Then give them `vertical-align:middle;`.

```
h1 {
    text-shadow: #6A6A6A 1px -2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    display:inline-block; /* added */
    vertical-align:middle;/* added */
}
.logoandtext img {
    display:inline-block; /* added */
    vertical-align:middle; /*added */
}
```

You could tidy this up by having:

```
h1 {
    text-shadow: #6A6A6A 1px -2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.logoandtext img, h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uvf4gqfp/19/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
h1.title {
float: left;
margin: 15px 0 0;
}

.logoandtext {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uvf4gqfp/23/